# How to ssh into a Linux VM via powershell (posh SSH)

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh

The classic way to ssh into a Linux VM is using putty and uploading your private key (.ppk).

However, what I would like to do is create a connection to a Linux VM using Powershell and Posh SSH

I can't figure out how to reference the private key to create the connection. I have a Linux VM running in Oracle Cloud (OCI) and I am using the following command:

```
New-SSHSession ip_address -computer hostname -keyfile path_to_private_key
```

**Note:** I have converted my .ppk private key to openSSH format via puttygen

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using openssh, make sure your key is 1. loaded and 2. in the right file location (`~/.openssh/`)

Comment: what do you mean loaded? I'm just referencing the file path where the key is

Comment: What he want's to say is that your private key should be in `~/.openssh`, then you can omit `-Keyfile`. you didn't tell us if you are getting error messages.

Comment: Hmm okay - so what's the difference with putting the key there as opposed to just referencing the path? I don't get any error message, but rather the popup box for 'windows powershell credential request' Username pre-populates with my IP address and it wants a password (which I don't have any password)